# Bounding box calculation in groupplots suddenly fails?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Suddenly some graphs changed in my documents. I have not the slightest idea what changed but as of today the bounding box calculation for some plots created in `pgfplots` is going haywire. My MWE looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7} 

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group name=my plots, group size=1 by 1}]
    \nextgroupplot[xmin=0.05,] 
        \addplot {0};
\end{groupplot}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

And the non-expected output with lots of whitespace at the left:
[image]

This only happens in groupplots in combination with `xmin=`, not in normal plots but the document itself did not change.

Comment: This doesn't happen on my system. Does this only happen with the `standalone` class? If yes, what version of `standalone` are you using?

Comment: @Jake: The problem remains with the `article` class. I recently updated `pgfplots` and checked that everything was ok but might have missed something due to the externalization library.

Comment: @Jake, thanks for the hint that it works on your system. This made me pretty suspicious that it must have something to do with the pgfplots and tikz versions. I have a recent unstable build of pgfplots but not of tikz installed. Now updating both to the most recent version solved the problem.

Comment: Excellent! I guess we can close this question then?

Comment: @Jake, yes! I checked all my other groupplots and the problem is solved, thanks again!